# can not launch app on device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I installed Windows 8.1 RTM and installed VS2012 had a little problem while installing windows phone 8 sdk but i guess it is resolved now but still i have a weird problem.

Even i select "device" as the launch target when clicked the run button VS launches the app on the emulator not the phone. Surprisingly if i right click the project on solution explorer and select debug it this time launched app on the device.

Is there anybody faced with this kind of problem? I dont want to install everthing from scratch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was my fault, since the project build platform was x86 visual studio could not deploy the app to the device and hence launching the emulator. When i changed the build platform to Any CPU now it deploys my app to the device without any problem.